# Is it possible to set two view in the route?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I was wondering if it was possible to do something like this in my routes.js. This doesn't work, but I wanted to know if it was possible.

```
state('tabs.jobDetails', {
  url: '/jobDetail',
  cache: false,
  views: {
    function($ionicHistory) {
      if($ionicHistory.backTitle() === "Listings") {
        'home-tab'
      } else {
        'search-tab'
      }
    } {
      templateUrl: 'templates/jobDetails/jobDetails.html',
      controller: 'jobsCtrl'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Mb You should just return this values (`home-tab`, `search-tab`)? i.e. `return 'home-tab';` , `return 'search-tab';` now Your function returns nothing... Have You tried this?

Comment: @Razzka I tried it and I get an unexpected string error

Answer (score 0):

The views object should be like below format;

```
views: {
    "main": {
      template: "<h1>HELLO!</h1>"
    }
}
```

So you need to change you code to make this object. I'll suggest to put the  function outside .state and $stateprovider and call it in views.
Define a function outside like:

```
function setStateParams() {
    if($ionicHistory.backTitle() === "Listings") {
        return { 
            'home-tab': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/jobDetails/jobDetails.html',
                controller: 'jobsCtrl'
            }
        };
    } else {
        return { 
            'search-tab': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/jobDetails/jobDetails.html',
                controller: 'jobsCtrl'
            }
        };
    }
}
```

and call it in views object like:

```
views: setStateParams()
```

Comment: this throws an error in the route.js. The error is at

 templateUrl: 'templates/jobDetails/jobDetails.html',
        controller: 'jobsCtrl'


Where it doesn't acceot the ':' character. Any ideas on how to solve this ?

Comment: Sorry, it happened because the compiler took the function as the key name for the object instead of calling the function. I have edited the answer, please try it.